# Where should a body.appendChild snippet (helpcrunch chat) be added to a Vue single page application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Where should I add a livechat javascript snippet in a Vue SPA?

The snippet below adds a small chat on the right-bottom side of the web. The instructions of HelpCrunch state that the snippet below should be added to each page of the website

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(w,d){
  w.HelpCrunch=function(){w.HelpCrunch.q.push(arguments)};w.HelpCrunch.q=[];
  function r(){var s=document.createElement('script');s.async=1;s.type='text/javascript';s.src='https://widget.helpcrunch.com/';(d.body||d.head).appendChild(s);}
  if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',r)}else{w.addEventListener('load',r,false)}
})(window, document)
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  HelpCrunch('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', {
    applicationId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    applicationSecret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  });

  HelpCrunch('showChatWidget');
</script>
```

I've tried to add this snippet to the index.html where Vue injects all the code (and it works), but as far as I understand this is bad practice.

I've tried as well adding this in the main.js file inside the mounted() {} method of the Vue instance. It works, but I've noticed that refreshing the page won't add the chat, probably due to some sort of Vue caching.

Where should this be added?

Comment: Adding it to `index.html` seems perfectly fine to me. What's the concern?

Comment: to be honest I haven't seen any explicit reason to not add it in the index.html, it is just that I have never seen anyone doing that on similar cases :P anyway I would like to re-use the HelpCrunch object in other Vue components. If I create another .js file with that code and then import it in index.html with script src="", it won't work. How could I make this work?

Comment: I'm assuming that you use vuejs with webpack. 


You could put it in some file, eg `help-crunch.js`, and at the bottom of the file export HelpCrunch object (using `export default HelpCrunch`).

Then you can import the file (`import HelpCrunch from '<path_to_file>'`) and use it whenever you need. As far as i know it should be one and the same instance everywhere you import it.